# Nexus helm proxy repo

Tags: proxy, kubernetes-helm, nexus

Have a quick question on helm setup... I created a repo (helm-proxy) on Nexus and tried to add the repo via helm client but got this error " Error: looks like "http://xxxxx:8081/repository/helm-proxy/" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch http://3.231.230.88:8081/repository/helm-proxy/index.yaml : 404 Not Found...

I dont find any issues in adding the helm  hosted repo as the index.html got created along with the repo creation but  helm-proxy rep there is no index.html... Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the value of the `Location of the remote repository being proxied` (URL-value) in your proxy configuration is correct.

correct means it works with `URL-value/index.yaml`

It has nothing to do with helm-hosted as helm-hosted generates its own index.yaml on creating it.